# Angular2 multiple custom pipes

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe

I am building angular2 app using es5. I have one screen where i have two search input fields to filter two different list.

For that I have defined two different pipe as mentioned below

```
(function(app) {
    app.filterPipe1 = ng.core.Pipe({
        name : "filter1",
        pure:true
    }).Class({
        constructor : function() {
        }, // <<< ---
        transform : function(values, args) {
        return values.filter(function(value) {
                    return value.title.toLowerCase().startsWith(args[0].toLowerCase());
                });
        }
    });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));


(function(app) {
    app.filterPipe2 = ng.core.Pipe({
        name : "filter2",
        pure:true
    }).Class({
        constructor : function() {
        }, // <<< ---
        transform : function(values, args) {


                return values.filter(function(value) {
                    return value.title.toLowerCase().startsWith(args[0].toLowerCase());
                });

        }
    });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

component1.js

```
app.component1 = ng.core
        .Component(
                {
                    directives : [ ng.router.ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
                            app.componenttest ],
                    pipes : [ app.filterPipe1,app.filterPipe2 ],
                    templateUrl : 'test1.html'
                })
```

I am getting below errors when running it "Cannot find pipe"

Also interesting thing is when I remove any one of declaration from pipes in component,it is working.

**Updated**

used filter in html as below

```
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search"
                                            [(ngModel)]="inputSearch1">

<li
                                        *ngFor="#category of categoryList |  filter1:inputSearch1 #i=index">





    <input type="text" placeholder="Search"
                                            [(ngModel)]="inputSearch2">

<li
                                        *ngFor="#objective of objectiveList |  filter2:inputSearch2 #i=index">
```

Anybody has faced this issue?

Comment: How do you use it? Is "Cannot find pipe" the full error message?

Comment: I am adding it in html after list.  error message:
Error: Cannot find pipe 'categoryFilter'.
    at new BaseException (exceptions.ts:10)
    at ProtoPipes.get (pipes.ts:32)
    at Pipes.get (pipes.ts:48)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.ChangeDetector_class6_0.detectChangesInRecordsInternal (viewFactory_class6:612)
    at

Comment: Your pipes are named `filter1` and `filter2` not `categoryFilter`. Can you please add the code that shows how you use it?

Comment: yeah, I have modified names for pipes and component but filter name is rightly used in html. I am sure about it as because If I remove any one of two filters in declaration ,it is working fine independently. Issue is when I am using both filters

Comment: How can I verify it is rightly used? ;-)

Comment: I think there should be a `;` before `#i=index`. Can you please try?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114351/discussion-between-chikka-anddev-and-gunter-zochbauer).